# Calling a function without losing that data that the function had before?

Tags: c, function, variables

I picked up the bad habit of Global Variables early on, So ive been trying to distance myself by using local variables and learning call by reference/value which isn't so bad until I run into a problem like this, say I have a function Menu() which contains a main menu, and an array, then from the Menu I'd go to a function and do stuff with the Array, now I usually get stuck here my functions are usually of void type, but usually for my programs I use a if selection to get back to the Menu, like `If(userinput ==2){Menu();}` usually this causes two problems 1. When I enter Menu it resets all the variable values
2.If i have this function in multiple places it will start giving me parameter errors.

These problems discourage me and make me lean towards the side of Global Variables.

```
Example:

menu(){
    int array[100];
    functionadd(array);
}

functionadd(array[])
{
    int userinput;
    do{ 
        //lets the just say here the program does things to my array.
        // usually when I want to go back to the menu I'd do something like this
        printf("Again or back to menu?1(Again) or 2(Menu)")
            scanf_s("%d%[^\n]", &userinput); '\n'==getchar();
    } while(userinput == 1)
    if(userinput != 2){Menu();} /*this would bring me back to
        the menu but my array would be back to as its original state
        when it was called in Menu I understand why this happens I
        just need to learn how to counter act it*/
}
```

Comment: How about some code too, along with this?

Comment: Could you please provide a [small, self-contained code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates what you're talking about here? It would help others to fully understand the situation you have in mind. Depending on the circumstances, you might use a `static` variable, or use a "state tracking" structure (which could be passed to functions via a pointer). In fact, global variables might be the way to go in some cases - give us a specific use case, so that we have some context for your question.

Comment: When you write menu() you are *asking* for a fresh menu... So if that isn't what you want then don't do that...

Comment: What you desribed sounds like you are recursing, which is not good at all.  You should be returning instead, and having a loop at the top level.  But without seeing any code, I'm just guessing at what you're doing.

Comment: I think you have to use `static` in this case. You have already an answer here.

Comment: @JS1 added an example

Comment: @GoBusto I added information

Comment: @PrerakSola added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You're calling is something like this:

```
    main()
    {
       menu();
    }

    menu()
    {
       yourfunction();
    }

    yourfunction()
   {
      if(userinput==2)
           menu();
   }
```

Here, you can observe that you're again calling menu() but not returning back..
If you're at the depth in menu(), if you'll exit, will return to yourfunction() but not the main().

I'll recommend you to use codes similar to the following:

```
menu()
{

     do
     {
        yourfunction();//call your function
        //after the completion ask to continue
        printf("Do you want to continue? (Y/N) ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
     }while(choice=='y'||choice=='Y');

 }

 void yourfunction()
{
         //do only functional job
}
```

This will help you to return to the menu() and ask you for the continuation.
And also the values will remain as you want them to.

**Edit**:

Or if you want to stick to your habit of programming.
Simply tell the program what to do when user input is 1 (i.e. not equal to 2)
And don't define anything when 2 is input.
It will automatically return to menu()

```
 menu()
    {
       yourfunction();
    }

Yourfunction()
{
  if(userinput==1)
   {
    // do this
   }
}
```

Or other way:

```
 menu()
    {
       yourfunction();
    }
Yourfuntion()
{
  if(userinput!=2)
   {
    //do this
   }
}
```

If the function gets userinput as 2 it will get back to menu().

Over.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some pseudo code to not have a variable to be "reset" with static keyword:

```
int Menu(){
    static int remember = 0;
    remember++;
    return remember;
}

int main(){
    printf("remember = %d\n", Menu());
    printf("remember = %d\n", Menu());
    printf("remember = %d", Menu());
}
```

output:

remember = 1

remember = 2

remember = 3

**Notice** that a global variable is, like Ron says, is a variable for the lifetime of the program. So is a static variable, but in this case it isn't accessible in another function. Also, a static variable isn't really thread safe

> "All non-local state must be accessed through atomic operations and
>   the data-structures must also be reentrant."

Comment: Would probably do good to mention that these are as discouraged as global variables for being non-thread-safe. Technically, static locals are also "globals", but with a limited scope.

Comment: If statics are unsafe what should I use? I don't want to learn bad habits but it seems like for school project/programs globals and statics seem to make the assignment much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason people discourage overuse of global variables is because those variables will be taking memory for the life of the program (process really).

But, in this specific case, that's the behavior you want. You want to remember the state of the menu between calls, and you can either implement a structure yourself and save the state in the calling function, or you can simply declare the variable globally.

What irks people is when *every* variable is global, regardless of whether they need to be. In a language like C, which basically only survives because of its ability to manually manage memory to the utmost efficiency, it hurts our brains to see people wasting it. In general, it's a code smell to see any global variables that aren't constants. As a commenter has pointed out, there *are* other reasons to avoid using globals. Rather than iterate through them all, I'll leave this here: [why globals are bad](http://bit.ly/1EzWm3n)

Note, I'm not trying to be mean, just not sure which of those pages is the best resource, so I gave OP all of them.

Edit: a few other points. You also could easily accomplish what you need by either passing a pointer containing the value you may or may not edit within the function as a parameter, but the solution I would probably implement given what you've said is like this:

```
int choice = menu(); 
case (choice ):
//logic here
```

Comment: Memory is the least of your concerns. The main issue is that it is difficult to control how that data will be used/changed by the program; the issue appears principally when you use globals to pass data between functions (instead of using parameters), as it is very difficult to control/find out which code is assigning values to the variables, and can lead to all kind of race conditions.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm not arguing that there are other problems; mostly to do with "who the hell is changing my variable" and multithreading, as you've correctly pointed out. But, he said he's new, and likely won't run into either of those for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you save a variable like `static` you'll not lose the data the function had before, cause the variable won't be destroyed at the end if the function and the stack won't be cleaned. Example:

```
static int var=0;
var++;
return var;
```

If you call the function 10 times the variable will be increased ten times.

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should take note of the following:

- In C, all parameters are passed using `call by value`.
- When you passing an array as parameter to a function, it decays as a pointer to the first element of the array.

`Call by value` doesn't mean you can't modify some function's local variable from another function. For that, you pass a pointer as parameter and then from the callee function assign value to its dereferenced stated.

eg:

```
void f(int *c)
{
    *c = 7;
}

int main(void)
{
    int count = 4;
    f(&count);
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```